# What is the difference "I made him angry" and "I got him angry"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

These are from dictionaries, and it is hard to distinguish "**make somebody/something + adj**" and "**get somebody/something + adj**" and grammar books seldom talk about them

> [Get](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get)
>
> 18 MAKE SOMEBODY/SOMETHING BECOME SOMETHING [transitive] to make
> someone or something change to a new feeling, situation, or state
>
> Sometimes she gets me so angry!
>
> Don’t get the children too excited.
>
> He was terrified of getting her pregnant.
>
> It took them 15 minutes to get the boat ready.

====

> [make](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1?q=make)
>
> make somebody/something/yourself + adj. to cause somebody/something to
> feel, show or have a particular quality; to cause somebody/something
> to be or become something
>
> The news made him very happy.
>
> She made her objections clear.
>
> Technology promises to make our lives easier.
>
> He made it clear that he objected.
>
> The full story was never made public.

What is the difference "**I made him angry**" and "**I got him angry**"?

Answer (score 0):

> I made him angry.

Making him angry may not have been your intention. You may have said or done something and, even though it wasn't something you expected, it made him angry.

> I got him angry.

Getting him angry may have been your intention all along. You wanted him angry, and you got him angry.

Comment: does that apply for all other examples, for example, "**I made my dress dirty**" and "**I got my dress dirty**"

Comment: I don't think it generalizes, this one is more idiomatic.

Comment: E.g. "I made him eat" means you forced someone to eat.

Comment: @Barmar: Whereas "I got him to eat" could mean "I coaxed him into having breakfast." Stands to reason.

Comment: @Tom: "I made my dress dirty" sounds a bit awkward, not to mention ambiguous. "I got my dress dirty" sounds ok.

Comment: Does "I got my dress dirty" mean that is my intention to cause my dress dirty?

Comment: @Tom: Could be. However, I take my previous comment back. A dress is an inanimate object. Making a LIVING BEING do something means, by and large, FORCING them to do it. Getting a living being to do something is using a variety of means (i.e. not necessarily using force). It's more complicated with inanimate objects.

Comment: But you said "Making him angry may not have been your intention." and that means "I didn't intend to make him angry" and there is no "**Force**" here because it happened "**by chance**". But then you said "**Make**" means "**force**". They are contradictory

Comment: @Yes. I'm sorry. Language can come across as contradictory sometimes. "While designing the auditorium, I made the walls dark blue." The sentence describes a single decision followed by a single action. "While working on the auditorium, I finally got the walls to be dark blue - in accordance with the original plan." This one would denote multiple efforts (perhaps the paint wasn't quite right initially, which necessitated taking another pass - or something). Everything depends on the concept.

Comment: If you find my answer inadequate (far being it from me to claim infallibility), by all means wait for other answers. Your question is a good one.

Comment: Also, do note that in your OP - "The news made him very happy" is quite natural, whilst "The news got him happy" would sound rather stupid. Go figure.